# getting friends list and photos of facebook with ios

Tags: ios, facebook

Using the facebook ios sdk, how can I get an `NSArray` of all my friends list with their photos?

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:
 @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"read_friendlists"]];

loginView.delegate = self;

loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame, (self.view.center.x - (loginView.frame.size.width / 2)), 250);

[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by doing an fql request

With the iOS Facebook sdk you can an request like this:

```
- (IBAction)queryButtonAction:(id)sender {
// Query to fetch the active user's friends, limit to 25.
NSString *query =
@"SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN "
@"(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 25)";
// Set up the query parameter
NSDictionary *queryParam = @{ @"q": query };
// Make the API request that uses FQL
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
    }
}];
```

}

This is an example taken from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph#fql

Read more about this here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph

The friendlist is documented here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friendlist/

Comment: can u help me please with the code snippet for this ? i was read the example but there is nothing with what i needed

Comment: With what exactly do u need help? The snippet should return an id object with 25 "objects" from the friendslist. You can access specific property by using result["property"]